# When paging large data with php, I cannot access all time ranges in the database

Tags: php, database, pagination

On the Dashboard screen, 3, 5, 15, 60 minutes data of each record is calculated and printed. I need to paginate because there is a lot of data in the database. But when I paginate, I usually cannot calculate 5, 15, 60 minutes data. That is, 10 records on each page, but calculate for all minute data. Thank you in advance

```
$resultArray = [];

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$records_per_page = 20;
$start_from = ($page - 1) * $records_per_page;

$query = "
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 3 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val3min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 5 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val5min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 15 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val15min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 60 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val60min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 120 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val120min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 240 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val240min,
SUM(CASE WHEN tt.tx_timeStamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 720 * 60 THEN tt.tx_value ELSE 0 END) AS val720min,
tt.tx_timeStamp,
tt.tx_tokenSymbol,
tt.tx_action,
tt.tx_value,
ts.ts_current_price,
ts.ts_pricePercent,
ts.ts_name,
ts.ts_id,
ts.ts_images
FROM
tokentx AS tt
INNER JOIN
tokensymbol AS ts
ON tt.tx_contractAddress = ts.ts_contract_address
WHERE tt.tx_contractAddress = ts.ts_contract_address AND tt.tx_action != 'non'
GROUP BY tt.tx_timeStamp, tt.tx_tokenSymbol, tt.tx_action, tt.tx_value, ts.ts_current_price, ts.ts_name, ts.ts_id, ts.ts_images, ts.ts_pricePercent
ORDER BY tt.tx_timeStamp DESC
LIMIT
$start_from, $records_per_page
";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$results) {
    echo "No data..";
    return;
}

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $ts_current_price = $row['ts_current_price'];
    $ts_pricePercent = $row['ts_pricePercent'];
    $tokenSymbol = $row['tx_tokenSymbol'];
    $action = $row['tx_action'];
    $value = $row['tx_value'];
    $images = $row['ts_images'];
    $timeStamp = $row['tx_timeStamp'];
    $previusTime = $row['tx_timeStamp'];
    $timeframes = [3, 5, 15, 60, 120, 240, 720];

    foreach ($timeframes as $varb) {
        ${"val{$varb}min"} = $row["val{$varb}min"];
    }

    if (!isset($resultArray[$tokenSymbol])) {
        $resultArray[$tokenSymbol] = [
            'tx_tokenSymbol' => $tokenSymbol,
            'ts_current_price' => $ts_current_price,
            'ts_pricePercent' => $ts_pricePercent,
            'images' => $images,
            'inT3' => 0,
            'outT3' => 0,
            'inT5' => 0,
            'outT5' => 0,
            'inT15' => 0,
            'outT15' => 0,
            'inT60' => 0,
            'outT60' => 0,
            'inT120' => 0,
            'outT120' => 0,
            'inT240' => 0,
            'outT240' => 0,
            'inT720' => 0,
            'outT720' => 0,
            'perc3' => 0,
            'perc5' => 0,
            'perc15' => 0,
            'perc60' => 0,
            'perc120' => 0,
            'perc240' => 0,
            'perc720' => 0,
            'timeStamp' => $timeStamp,
            'previusTime' => $previusTime
        ];
    }

    if (!isset($resultArray[$tokenSymbol]) || $timeStamp > $resultArray[$tokenSymbol]['timeStamp']) {
        $resultArray[$tokenSymbol]['timeStamp'] = $timeStamp;
    }

    $multiplier = ($action == 'in') ? 1 : -1;
    $timeframes = [3, 5, 15, 60, 120, 240, 720];

    foreach ($timeframes as $varb) {
        $inKey = "inT$varb";
        $outKey = "outT$varb";
        $percKey = "perc$varb";

        $resultArray[$tokenSymbol][$inKey] += ($multiplier == 1) ? ${"val{$varb}min"} * $ts_current_price : 0;
        $resultArray[$tokenSymbol][$outKey] += ($multiplier == -1) ? ${"val{$varb}min"} * $ts_current_price : 0;

        ${"inT$varb"} = $resultArray[$tokenSymbol][$inKey];
        ${"outT$varb"} = $resultArray[$tokenSymbol][$outKey];

        $inT = ${"inT$varb"};
        $outT = ${"outT$varb"};

        if ($inT > 0) {
            ${"perc$varb"} = abs(intval((($outT - $inT) / $inT) * 100));
        } elseif ($outT > 0) {
            ${"perc$varb"} = abs(intval((($inT - $outT) / $outT) * 100));
        } else {
            ${"perc$varb"} = 0;
        }
        $resultArray[$tokenSymbol][$percKey] = ${"perc$varb"};
    }
}

echo '<p class="pop">LASTEST TOKENS</p>';
echo '<div class="featuredContainer">';
foreach ($resultArray as $tokenSymbol => $row) {
    $timestamp = $row['timeStamp'];
    $tokenLogo = $row['images'];
    $timeframes = [3, 5, 15, 60, 120];

    foreach ($timeframes as $varb) {
        ${"outT$varb"} = $row["outT$varb"];
        ${"inT$varb"} = $row["inT$varb"];
        ${"perc$varb"} = $row["perc$varb"];
    }

    $colorClass = ($ts_pricePercent >= 0) ? 'positive' : 'negative';
    $colorClass2 = ($outT240 > 5000000) ? 'positive' : 'none';

    echo '<div class="featuredChild">';
    echo '<div class="tokensymbol">';
    echo "<strong><a class=".$colorClass2." target=_blank href=". "analysis/analysis.php?symbol=" . $tokenSymbol . "> " . $tokenSymbol . "</strong><br>";
    echo "<img class=logo ".$colorClass2." src=" . $tokenLogo. " title=" . $tokenSymbol . "></a>";
    echo "<label class=date>
    <span>last update:</span>" . date("d/m/y H:i", $timestamp) . "
    <br>
    <span class=sep>cmc 24h: <span class=" . $colorClass . ">" . sprintf("%.2f", $ts_pricePercent) . "%</span></label>";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="symbolrow">';

    $timeframes = [
        '3m' => ['perc' => $perc3, 'outT' => $outT3, 'inT' => $inT3],
        '5m' => ['perc' => $perc5, 'outT' => $outT5, 'inT' => $inT5],
        '15m' => ['perc' => $perc15, 'outT' => $outT15, 'inT' => $inT15],
        '1h' => ['perc' => $perc60, 'outT' => $outT60, 'inT' => $inT60]
    ];

    foreach ($timeframes as $interval => $data) {
        if (isset($data['perc'])) {
            outputRow($interval, $data['perc'], $data['outT'], $data['inT']);
        }
        unset($data, $interval);
    }

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

echo '</div>';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total
FROM tokentx tt
INNER JOIN tokensymbol AS ts ON tt.tx_contractAddress = ts.ts_contract_address
WHERE tt.tx_contractAddress = ts.ts_contract_address AND tt.tx_action != 'non'";
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_records = $row['total'];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records_per_page);

echo "<div class='pagination'>";

if ($total_pages > 10) {
    if ($page > 1) {
        echo "<a href='dashboard.php?page=1'>&lt;&lt;</a> "; 
        echo "<a href='dashboard.php?page=" . ($page - 1) . "'>&lt;</a> "; 
    }

    for ($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $total_pages); $i++) {
        echo ($i == $page) ? "<strong><a href='dashboard.php?page=$i'>$i</a></strong> " : "<a href='dashboard.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }

    if ($page < $total_pages) {
        echo "<a href='dashboard.php?page=" . ($page + 1) . "'>&gt;</a> "; 
        echo "<a href='dashboard.php?page=$total_pages'>&gt;&gt;</a> "; 
    }
} else {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
        echo "<a href='dashboard.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Where is the PHP?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Not all that clear what exactly you are calculating (hint: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)), but if you are saying that your calculation needs to go over _all_ the records, no exceptions, no matter what "range" of records is getting shown on the current page - then you basically don't have any other option, than to remove the LIMIT portion from your query, and then pick out only the records relevant for the current page out of that _full_ result set, using PHP.

Comment: You didn't say how much data you have there overall, but if it is not too much to be _transported_ to the client in one go - then it would perhaps make more sense to run the query only once, to return _all_ data - and then use something like https://datatables.net on the client side, to handle pagination within that data set.